# KSoap2 on Android freezing the device instead of making a webservice call

Tags: java, android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to connect to **.NET 4.0** webservice I created for receiving SOAP-calls from Android-devices, now hosted on **local IIS** for testing purposes.

I found out that **ksoap2** would be an excellent class library for doing what i want to do. Downloaded the .jar package from https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/ and started pounding the keyboard in ecstacy... with my fingers.

The amount of information being sent is from few kilobytes to few megabytes.

### What is working

`HttpTransportSE.call(String, SoapSerializationEnvelope)`-method works perfectly while still in Eclipse's Android emulator, sending the call to webservice hosted in local IIS. Even tested that the webservice receives empty calls from trying to open the service address from a web browser in the same local area network.

### What doesn't work

When I copy the .apk-file to an Android device, install it, start it and trying to make the call, the whole program *freezes* without making the call.

As you can see from a code block presented some lines after that possible errors are being taken into account: In emulated environment a successful call returns a *SoapPrimitive*-object or flows into the correct *catch block* generating an error message for the user according to the current situation.

Then on live Android device, program loses it's responsivity forever and has to be terminated from application menu.

### What have i tried

I removed the call from the asynchronous method, and tried calling it straight from an anonymous inner function assigned for a button click-event.

Tried not trying to get a response, just making the call.

Tried getting a logcat-program for the device to see what's happening behind the UI, found two, they needed root access, which i don't have in the device. This is why i don't have any logcats to show you, and showing the emulator logcat would probably(?) be useless because it works fine there.

Not trying to connect to localhost.

Tried installing the program on older Lenovo-tablet running *Android 4.2.2* and on brand new Samsung Galaxy Tab, both would have the same problem while otherwise working well.

### The code

Here's the asynchronous method for making the call in device/emulator, where variables `str_URL` and `soapRequest` are a correct service address (checked) and a well formed SoapObject respectively:

```
@Override
protected WebServiceResult doInBackground(Void... v) {
    WebServiceResult _ret;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope= new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet=true;
    soapEnvelope.setAddAdornments(false);
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapRequest);
    HttpTransportSE conn = new HttpTransportSE(str_URL);
    conn.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
    conn.debug = true;
    try {
        conn.call(str_ACTION, soapEnvelope); 
        SoapObject o = (SoapObject)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
        _ret = new WebServiceResult(o, WebServiceResultEnum.ok);
    } catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException e) {
        _ret = new WebServiceResult(null, WebServiceResultEnum.keskeytys);
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        _ret = new WebServiceResult(null, WebServiceResultEnum.httpVirhe);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        _ret = new WebServiceResult(null, WebServiceResultEnum.vaara_muoto);
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        _ret = new WebServiceResult(null, WebServiceResultEnum.aikakatkaisu);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _ret = new WebServiceResult(null, WebServiceResultEnum.keskeytys);
    }
    return _ret;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, logcat **does not** require root.  If you are doing your network operation in the background, it **will not** freeze your UI, unless you were unwise enough to have your UI thread wait on the background operation or its result.

Comment: You can view the logcat in your IDE, you don't need an app for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had declared the **minimum SDK as 14** and **target SDK as 17** in *AndroidManifest.xml*. I didn't use any fancy things in newer sdk's so i lowered the target SDK to the same level as minimum SDK, 14. I also had an **Avast! Antivirus** service running on the tablet which i removed.

This solved my problem. It could be that probably the Avast! antivirus-program wanted to block all communications from applications not downloaded from Play-store. I don't know if changing the target SDK had much effect really.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are doing something like this:

```
YourAsyncTask task = new YourAsyncTask();
WebServiceResult result = task.doInBackground();
```

Because that would be wrong, completely wrong. If you call `doInBackground()` directly it will run in the same `Thread` and not in a new one. You need to start the `AsyncTask` with `execute()` like this:

```
YourAsyncTask task = new YourAsyncTask();
task.execute();
```

---

You need to implement the `AsyncTask` like this:

```
public class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, WebServiceResult> {

    public interface FinishedListener {
        public void onFinished(WebServiceResult result);
    }

    private final FinishedListener finishedListener;

    public ExampleTask(FinishedListener listener) {
        this.finishedListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected WebServiceResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
        WebServiceResult result = ...;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(WebServiceResult result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(this.finishedListener != null) {
            this.finishedListener.onFinished(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And if you implemented it that way you can use it like this:

```
ExampleTask task = new ExampleTask(new ExampleTask.FinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFinished(WebServiceResult result) {
        // This will be called if the task has finished
    }
});
task.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive account on using asynchronous methods correctly. I didn't know all of that!

But as i said already in original post that i tried already removing the call to webservice out of asynchronous method and making the call straight in UI. I know Android doesn't like network operations in main thread, that's why i have a catch-block for it so i could see if the call works at all.

EDIT: Submitted comment prematurely. Continuing:

So i made the changes exactly as you instructed, but still the program freezes on real device and working on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same question as you. When it goes to the method `transport.call`, it pauses, and for a while, it throws a timeout problem. At first, I thought maybe the network was poor, but the server logcat shows it is not the problem. The request was fine and the response was good. My business process is like below:

First, I get a list from the server through ksoap inner a child thread, then cycle the list, send a ksoap request based on every item of the list. It means it will send another `list.size()` request. When debugging in a real device the above problems occured. I solved it by starting a new child thread after getting the list and making all the `list.size` requests in the new child thread. So, ksoap use in android may cause thread block which leads to ioexception. So when you put it in a new thread, it escapes from the parent catch exception and works fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).